# HAPROXY regsub match '?' questionmark

Tags: haproxy, regex

In HAproxy replacing the incoming url with some data.
This is the incoming path:

```
/powerbi?redirectSuccessUrl=/reports
```

I want to match:

```
/powerbi?
```

replace it with

```
clientId=${clientId}&
```

And final outcome must be:

```
/powerbi?clientId=${clientId}&redirectSuccessUrl=/reports
```

I tried this

```
http-request set-path %[path, regsub(^/powerbi\?,/powerbi?clientId="${clientId}"&]
```

But getting two questionmarks(near powerBi and before redirectSuccessUrl):

```
/powerbi?clientId=${clientId}&?redirectSuccessUrl=/reports
```

How to match '?' with regsub? I've tried '?'  , '[?]', '[\?]'. None of these matches a questionmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't match for `?`, because it seperates `path` part of uri from `query string` part in haproxy and haproxy already does that for you.
You want to change query string, but altered path. That's why your changes ended up on the wrong side of `?`.
Instead use `http-request set-query`, like this:

```
http-request set-query clientId=${clientId}&%[query]
```

In case you may want to properly set query depending on whether original uri had query or not, you may try this:

```
http-request set-query clientId=${clientId}&%[query] if { query -m found }
http-request set-query clientId=${clientId} unless { query -m found }
```

This avoids trailing `&` in case there was no query string in uri.

Alternatively you may try some magic regexp with `set-uri` and set whole uri instead, but be very careful and remember that uri may come as `relative uri` (e.g. `/foobar?arg1=val1&arg2=val2`) or `absolute uri` (e.g. `https://example.com:6789/foobar?arg1=val1&arg2=val2`) and then conjuring proper regexp to handle both will be far more difficult than simply using `set-path` and `set-query` as above.
More about relative and absolute uri in [haproxy docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#1.2.1)

UPDATE in response to comment

You can match for path part and change query string, e.g.:

```
acl url_powerbi path_beg /powerbi
acl query_string_found query -m found
http-request set-query clientId=${clientId}&%[query] if url_powerbi query_string_found
http-request set-query clientId=${clientId} if url_powerbi !query_string_found
```

Comment: This is kind of a workaround. This will add the query to all endpoints. I only want it to add the query only if it is /powerbi . There are multiple endpoints which do not need the query param

Comment: Thanks for the update :)